# Windows 10 Batchfile Issue

Tags: batch-file, scripting, permissions, parallels

I have a batch file that successfully runs on my physical Windows 10 installation. When I run my batch script on my Parallels VM, I'm running into something odd when trying to access a file.

First to make sure the path exists...

`dir %BASE_DIR%\Hex /b`

```
myFile.hex
myOtherFile.hex
myOtherOtherfile.hex
```

​

```
FOR /f "tokens=1" %%A in ('FIND ":0D001D" %BASE_DIR%\Hex\myFile.hex') DO SET "var=%%A"
```

However once the above line of code is reached, I see many errors and my script gets 'stuck', not returning or moving forward in execution.

```
FIND: ':0D001D': No such file or directory
FIND: '/C/$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-18': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/PerfLogs': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Program Files/Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection/Classification/Configuration': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Program Files/WindowsApps': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Program Files (x86)/Google/CrashReports': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Crypto/PCPKSP/WindowsAIK': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Crypto/RSA/S-1-5-18': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Crypto/SystemKeys': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Network/Downloader': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Provisioning/AssetCache': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Search/Data': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/SmsRouter': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Spectrum': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/AppRepository': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/LfSvc': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Models': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/PackagedEventProviders': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Power Efficiency Diagnostics': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/SystemData': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/WER/ReportArchive/Critical_10.0.18362.411_1_6f9760ffa3e63ff84c64aa7ab4f527710771a_00000000_3d87bdbe-7e1a-43c9-b116-4a5cdaebf273': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/WER/ReportArchive/Critical_10.0.18362.590_1_4856e7ad9954657d2dde08e392fbeba970e28e_00000000_59d7e55a-c16b-4ea0-a0e8-93f702eeeb33': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/WER/ReportArchive/NonCritical_0x8050a003_6741cf896adcaafe92f5ed3ce3da52c9b8a4853_00000000_2ef1b5e5-8133-49a6-9ed5-a568f9334798': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/WER/ReportArchive/NonCritical_Microsoft Window_e9afe9103a18beaab280d4a888567f54467a971c_00000000_0aa6dae0-a9da-418e-a26d-cef36c198a1f': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/WER/ReportArchive/NonCritical_Microsoft Window_e9afe9103a18beaab280d4a888567f54467a971c_00000000_20e0f268-ead2-4aef-9bd3-629752ac0b4d': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/WER/ReportArchive/NonCritical_Microsoft Window_e9afe9103a18beaab280d4a888567f54467a971c_00000000_b1cd6804-0625-48a7-9437-ee0929ffd8b2': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/WER/ReportArchive/NonCritical_Update;ScanForUp_6c17da3ab194b05faf5d7ee84f332f768c21c_00000000_7521c288-1b33-4a0c-9ac3-1aa608f72327': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/WER/ReportArchive/NonCritical_Update;ScanForUp_6c17da3ab194b05faf5d7ee84f332f768c21c_00000000_ae4ce85f-ac81-420e-8783-b45a9685da53': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/WER/ReportArchive/NonCritical_Update;ScanForUp_6c17da3ab194b05faf5d7ee84f332f768c21c_00000000_e7bb2399-4fda-4cd0-963c-45b69f58ddad': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/WER/ReportArchive/NonCritical_Update;_6cfb995959e9406665d01031df0de24951af941_00000000_3e7a2b95-3b55-4ac1-9d18-343963acde85': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/wfp': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows Defender/Clean Store': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows Defender/Features': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows Defender/LocalCopy': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows Defender/Network Inspection System': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows Defender/Quarantine': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows Defender/Scans': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows Defender/Support': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection/Cache': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection/Cyber': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection/DataCollection': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection/Downloads': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection/Temp/PSScriptOutputs': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection/Trace': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows NT/MSFax': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/Packages': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/ProgramData/WindowsHolographicDevices': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Recovery': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/System Volume Information': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Users/gary/AppData/Local/ElevatedDiagnostics': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Windows/appcompat/Programs': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Windows/CSC/v2.0.6': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Windows/LiveKernelReports': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Windows/Logs/SystemRestore': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Windows/ModemLogs': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Windows/PLA/Reports': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Windows/PLA/Rules': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Windows/PLA/Templates': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Windows/Prefetch': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Windows/Provisioning/Autopilot': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Windows/Resources/Themes/aero/VSCache': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Windows/security/audit': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Windows/security/cap': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Windows/ServiceProfiles/LocalService': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Windows/ServiceProfiles/NetworkService': Permission denied
FIND: '/C/Windows/ServiceState': Permission denied​
```

The first error is pretty straightforward, it claims the directory does not exist. Why is permission denied when attempting to access these 'other' directories, and why would a simple FIND operation need to access them at all? Should a user with admin privileges be able to access these directories?

Edited for clarity.

Comment: `@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Find ":0D001D"^<"%BASE_DIR%\Hex\myFile.hex"') Do @Set "var=%%A"` would be how I would try it, _(`%BASE_DIR%` should be an actual Windows path and the file obviously must exist to read it)_.

Comment: To expand upon my previous comment, please open a Command Prompt window and enter `Find ":0D001D" "%BASE_DIR%\Hex\myFile.hex"` and take a look at the output, then repeat it with `Find ":0D001D"<"%BASE_DIR%\Hex\myFile.hex"`. Using the input redirection character makes a noticeable difference to the output.

Comment: @Compo Without the redirection character I can see that the full path to the filename is printed before the line I'm looking for. With the character only the line I'm looking for is printed. (on my physical windows 10 installation.) On my VM, `find: '0D001D' : No such file or directory`. `cd <full path to directory>` still navigates to the directory. (inside the directory) `find ":0D001D"<"myFile.hex"` also gives same error. Thank you